# how to add WPFUserControl to a StackPanel depending on condition in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a `StackPanel` in a WPF Form. And I do have 3 different WPF User Control that I need to load inside the panel depending on the condition. Any Ideas, I know it should be done in the behind code, tried to add the usercontrol to the stackPanel I was not able too find the add method. Do I need to user different control than the stack panel to do that?

```
<StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="1" x:Name="pnlRightMenu" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,403,-576,342" Grid.Column="1" Width="576" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Width="550" Background="#4C808080" Margin="0,-163,0,-126" >
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="btnRightMenuHide" Click="btnRightMenuHide_Click" Content="&gt;&gt;" Margin="-16,-191,0,0" FontSize="10" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.338,2.571" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any `UIElement` to the `StackPanel`'s `Children` collection:

```
pnlRightMenu.Children.Add(new UserControl1());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your button click event handler you'll want to switch through the conditions.

Use the switch to append a new instance of the user control to the StackPanel's Children collection:

```
private void btnRightMenuHide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (condition)
    {
        case "case 1":
            UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
            pnlRightMenu.Children.Add(uc1);
            break;
        case "case 2":
            UserControl2 uc2 = new UserControl2();
            pnlRightMenu.Children.Add(uc2);
            break;
        case "case 3":
            UserControl3 uc3 = new UserControl3();
            pnlRightMenu.Children.Add(uc3);
            break;
    }
}
```